# Why can't I split files when generating some TFrecord files?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

Why can't I split files when generating some TFrecords files?

I'm doing some job predicting protein stuctures. As you may know, one protein molecule might have different strands. So I need to split the list of the atoms into different TFrecords by the strand name.

The problem is, this code ended up by generating several TFrecords with nothing written. All blank.

Or, is there a method to split the strands while training my module? Then I could ignore this problem and put the strand name in the TFrecords as a feature.

'''
with all module imported and no errors raised
'''

```py
def generate_TFrecord(intPosition, endPosition, path):

    CrtS = x #x is the name of the current strand

    path = path + CrtS

    writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter('%s.tfrecord' %path)

    for i in range(intPosition, endPosition):

        if identifyCoreCarbon(i):

            vectros  = getVectors(i)
            features = {}
            '''
            feeding this dict
            '''
            tf_features = tf.train.Features(feature = features)
            tf_example  = tf.train.Example(features = tf_features)
            tf_serialized = tf_example.SerializeToString()
            writer.write(tf_serialized)
            '''
            if checkStrand(i) == False:
                writer.write(tf_serialized)
                intPosition = i
            '''
    writer.close()
'''
strand_index is a list of all the startpoint of a single strand
'''
for loop in strand_index:
    generate_TFrecord(loop, endPosition, path)




'''
________division___________

This code below works, but only generate a single tfrecord containing all the atom imformations.


writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter('%s.tfrecord' %path)
for i in range(0, endPosition):
    if identifyCoreCarbon(i):
        vectros  = getVectors(i)
        features = {}
        '''
        feeing features
        '''
        tf_features = tf.train.Features(feature = features)
        tf_example  = tf.train.Example(features = tf_features)
        tf_serialized = tf_example.SerializeToString()
        writer.write(tf_serialized)

writer.close()

'''
```

Comment: What is initial datatype and shape? What's this `features = {}` ?

Comment: The datashape has no problem, the total tfrecord work out just fine. I only got problem when spliting it.

Comment: I just omitted it cause it s irrelevant.